# What cities provide open data on rental building bylaw infractions?

Tags: data-request, government, city

We've developed a free mobile app (Vancouver RentalDog, currently in iTunes) that allows people to identify licensed rental buildings in Vancouver, which have outstanding bylaw infractions. Our data is pulled from [City of Vancouver](http://app.vancouver.ca/rps_net/List.aspx) and hosted on our server for access by mobile clients.

Any suggestions for contacts in other cities that have similar datasets? We're more than willing to work with IT staff to put their data into Open.

Comment: Duplicate of http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The City of Chicago publishes building violations: https://data.cityofchicago.org/Buildings/Building-Violations/22u3-xenr

Comment: Yes, this looks useful. We can search the Inspector Comments for 'rental' it returns a 114 results. Thanks, very much, @fgregg!